# Group values of a column by comma without using GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with data like below in MySQL:

```
id   name

1    john

1    jack

2    ankit
```

I need following output:

```
id   name

1    john,jack

2    ankit
```

I know that I can do this using GROUP_CONCAT but, I need above output without using GROUP_CONCAT.

Please help me on this.

Comment: And why you want to turn your hand around your neck to eat while you can eat easily by moving your hand to your mouth ?

Comment: I would to do this using SQL queries and not using any functions. If you know please help me.

Comment: You cannot do it in `SQL` without using functions. You can, however, do a plain `SELECT` with `ORDER BY id` and generate the desired result in the client code.

Answer (score 0):

Crazy answer for the crazy question !

```
SELECT id, MAX(NAME) FROM (
SELECT 
IF(@previd <>  id,  @name := NULL,  @name := @name), 
(IF(@name IS NULL, @name := NAME, @name := CONCAT(@name, ', ', NAME))) NAME, id, @previd := id FROM mytable, 
(SELECT  @name := NULL, @previd  := 0) s
ORDER BY id
) d
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL

```
    SELECT 
         id,
         STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(name AS VARCHAR(25)) [text()]
                FROM table1
                WHERE type = a.type
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') List_Output 
    FROM table1 a
    GROUP BY id
```